# Происхождение слова "сочельник"

Tags: этимология

Сегодня сочельник, с чем я всех форумчан и поздравляю.
Но мне вот было бы очень интересно узнать происхождение слова "сочельник". Это, как мы понимаем, канун Рождества. И, если навскидку, то слово родственно словам "сок", "сочиться" (как мне кажется). Но какая тут связь? И называли сочельником только канун Рождества или каких-то других праздников тоже?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**СОЧЕЛЬНИК** = день накануне праздника **Рождества Христова** или **Крещения**, когда соблюдается пост до вечера, а потом вкушается  **СОЧИВО**, т. е. варёная пшеница с мёдом...

http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0647.htm

**По Фасмеру:**

**СОЧИВО** *"сок, молоко из семян", "кушанье из семян"*, др.-русск. *сочиво "зерно чечевицы",* цслав. *сочиво...* Производное от **сок**...

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/47965/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: То есть, это то же самое, что кутья?

Answer (score -2):

Дословно "сочельник" - отхождение околоплодных вод перед родами. Именно поэтому Сочельник - навечерие Рождества. Источник информации - журнал "Наука и религия" не помню за какой год, кажется в конце 80-х начале 90-х. Но, поскольку столь "низменное" физиологическое толкование претит современным верующим, выдумываются какие-то невнятные, ничего не объясняющие кулинарные толкования. В старину верующие ничего "низменного" в естественной физиологии человека не усматривали, и назвали вещи своими именами.
Второй, крещенский, Сочельник - символический, соответственно перед духовным рождением - Крещением (впомним - у человека появляются как бы "духовные родители" - крёстные мать и отец).
У Иисуса Христа было ещё и третье рождение - божественное рождение, воскресение из мёртвых. Таким образом, пасхальный Сочельник также символический - предваряет божественное рождение.
Согласитесь, нелепо называть духовный праздник во имя постной лепёшки. Это столь же нелепо, как Пасху, Воскресение Христово, назвать "Куличихой" (или и того хуже - "Крашенояичницей"). Не логичнее ли предположить, что всё обстояло как раз наоборот - за постной лепёшкой закрепилось название, созвучное празднику?